# How to parse form data using Azure Functions

Tags: c#, function, azure, sendgrid

I am trying to get form data within an Azure function.

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    NameValueCollection col = req.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync().Result;   
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "OK");
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> Exception while executing function: System.Net.Http.Formatting: No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'FormDataCollection' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'.

I am trying to parse inbound emails via SendGrid as described here.
https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/Inbound_Parse_Webhook/setting_up_the_inbound_parse_webhook.html

The incoming request looks correct.

--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachments"

0
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text"

Hello world
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="subject"

Subject 
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="to"

Answer (score 5):

Since there doesn't appear to be a good way to convert an `IFormCollection` to a custom model / viewmodel type, I wrote an extension method for this.

It's a shame that Azure Functions v2/v3 doesn't support this out of the box yet.

```cs
public static class FormCollectionExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Attempts to bind a form collection to a model of type <typeparamref name="T" />.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The model type. Must have a public parameterless constructor.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="form">The form data to bind.</param>
    /// <returns>A new instance of type <typeparamref name="T" /> containing the form data.</returns>
    public static T BindToModel<T>(this IFormCollection form) where T : new()
    {
        var props = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        var formKeyMap = form.Keys.ToDictionary(k => k.ToUpper(), k => k);

        foreach (var p in props)
        {
            if (p.CanWrite && formKeyMap.ContainsKey(p.Name.ToUpper()))
            {
                p.SetValue(instance, form[formKeyMap[p.Name.ToUpper()]].FirstOrDefault());
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

This will attempt to bind an `IFormCollection` to whatever model type you pass in. Property names are case insensitive (i.e. you can map `firstname=Bob` to `public string FirstName { get; set; }`.

Usage:

```cs
var myModel = (await httpReq.ReadFormAsync()).BindToModel<MyModel>();
```

Comment: How can make for this to support Guid parsing ?

Comment: @BartCalixto This is a good place to start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.tryparse?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error message, you are using multipart/form-data as your request content type. But you haven't post any media type data to server.

If you just want to send some plain data to server, you could change the content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded and modify your request body as following format.

```
name=attachments&anothername=anothervalue
```

If you want to get the form data from multi part post, you could using MultipartFormDataStreamProvider.

```
string filePath = "set a temp path to store the uploaded file";
var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(filePath);
var multipartProvider = await req.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
var formData = multipartProvider.FormData;
```

Manually parse the content of request body.

```
string content = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
string formdata = content.Split(';')[1];
string[] namevalues = formdata.Split('&');
NameValueCollection col = new NameValueCollection();
foreach (string item in namevalues)
{
    string[] nameValueItem = item.Split('=');
    col.Add(nameValueItem[0], nameValueItem[1]);
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer to provide a way of getting form data from muti part request.

Comment: Thanks, but in this case, there is no uploaded file to point too.

Comment: Since the format of your request body doesn't meet application/x-www-form-urlencoded and multipart/form-data, I suggest you read the content of body using string content = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); and parse the content by yourself. I will modify my reply to provide the detail code.

Answer (score 0):

To read form data, you should use the method ReadAsMultipartAsync:

```
data = await req.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```