# a method to retrieve id_token from Azure AD body request

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps, azure-authentication

I'm following this WebApp-WebAPI [example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi). Is there a method to retrieve an id_token after a B2C user is authorized and the id_token is received within the body? I'm on Function app V3.

I receive the authorization response to replyURL in an azure Function app but the id_token coming in a body mixed with code and state data, and I can't seem to break it out or deserialize to json:

```
public class Function1
{
    internal class AuthToken
        {
            [JsonProperty("id_token")]
            public string id_Token { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("state")]
            public string StateToken { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("code")]
            public string CodeToken { get; set; }
        }

    private readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    [FunctionName("ReceiverAuth")]
    public static async Task<HttpStatusCode> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
    {
        //this works and shows id_token, state, code as text (also without the Encoding.UTF8 parameter)
        var requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body, Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEndAsync();

       //trying to separate the id_token data into json throws http500
        AuthToken authTok = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthToken>(requestBody);
        var idToken = authTok.id_Token;
}
```

Also tried but didn't change the result:

```
var decodedRequestBody = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(requestBody);
```

To my noob eyes Fiddler's body feels like the data is broken out but I can't separate the id_token on the req. received. Showing request header and webform and response.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is sent to you as [form data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code#sample-response), not JSON.

You need to use something like this:

```
var idToken = req.Form["id_token"];
```

Or you could try `FromForm` instead of `HttpRequest req`:

```
[FromForm] AuthToken authTok
```

If these don't work, check these: [How to parse form data using Azure Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45364128/how-to-parse-form-data-using-azure-functions?rq=1)

Comment: thanks a bunch @Alex AIT , life saver! var idToken = req.Form["id_token"]; worked :)